# I get an 'update has failed' notification - when it has actually worked

Tags: system-installation, updates, notification

This started with Ubuntu 21.04.  I expected it to be sorted out with 21.10 - but the error persists.  The scenario is that I get daily notifications of various updates to ubuntu itself or the apps.  I click install and the updates are installed but then I get a message to say the updates have failed when in actual fact they have succeeded!
I've got used to this, and it doesn't really bother me, but it would be nice to have the correct message appearing.
In short, how do I get a 'Success!' message rather than the current 'failure'?
TIA
Chris D

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us `sudo apt update`

Comment: Hit:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu impish InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease [110 kB]
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Hit:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease
Get:5 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease [110 kB]
Get:6 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Hit:7 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease          
Get:8 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports InRelease [101 kB]

Comment: Get:9 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Fetched 657 kB in 2s (396 kB/s)   
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up-to-date.
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'multiverse/source/Sources', as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu impish InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
 - and the three previous lines have many similar repeats!